# css hover creating border but pushing content

Tags: layout, hover, css

### Situation

I'm currently building a site and desire to have some elements create a border/outline upon hovering the mouse over them. This is simple enough to make work. For reference, please see the staging site at [Stagin area link](http://nlinstitute.nl-intl.com). I'm using the grid part of the latest bootstrap and the box-sizing model.

### Issue

I find that upon hovering, the content below that which is being hovered gets "pushed" far down below the next element. Using the stagin area as reference, I can change the behaviour through CSS to fix this on the left hand side or the right hand side but, not both at the same time.

### Code

Here is a snippet of the CSS I use to make the effect:

```css
.hover-border:hover {
   border: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
   display: block;
}
```

Using this method, anything but the first element behaves as expected. If I try this next snippet, the first element works but, then the others break:

```css
.hover-border:hover {
    border: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

For the sake of clarification with regard to properties inherited, I have set the margin/padding on the elements in question to '0 !important' for standard behaviour until hover

### Problem

How can I stop the element below from being pushed?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Instead of border you can give outline instead of border
outline: 3px solid #3A3A3A;

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Personally - I go with something along the lines of:

```
.hover-border {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  display: block;
}

.hover-border:hover {
  border: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this too. This is what you want to aim for, create a border by default but set it equal to either transparent or the color of the background it is on. That way, the space is already accounted for and hovering simply changes the border to visible

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you kindly. Trying to learn something new about the quirky way CSS works. Would I be right in assuming that when it comes to initial page rendering, defining those 3 pixels mean any of the child elements inherit properly and that's why it can render properly upon hover?

Comment: Imagine the content of your element is 100px X 100px to start with. The border wraps around the content - giving you an element that is 106px X 106px. If the border is only there on :hover, you are left with an element that is resized every time you mouse over it. The quick fix is to define the border to start with, but make it transparent :)

Answer (score 7):

The best solution to these issues is to use the box-sizing:border box property

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Then elements will retain whatever size you define but it will now INCLUDE borders and padding.

Comment: This doesn't always work and I really don't know why. Css is weird.

Comment: I thought that it would work, but actually it doesn't. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with less code:

```
.hover-border:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #3a3a3a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This will work.

```
.hover-border {
border: 3px solid transparent;
display: block;

}
.hover-border:hover{
border: 3px solid #3a3a3a;
}
```

Or

```
a.no-decoration, a.no-decoration img {
border: medium none;
color: inherit;
cursor: pointer;
outline: medium none;
text-decoration: none;
display: block; /*Added*/
border: 3px solid transparent; /*Added*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Borders are tough to work with when sizing is important.  I found it much better to use box-shadow, which just alters the background, so takes up no size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow?v=a

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```css
.hover-border:hover {
  outline: solid 4px #78CF82;
}
```

"Because the outline property is not a part of the element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline."

Comment: Please note that [`outline` is really intended to be used for indicating focus for keyboard users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#accessibility_concerns).  While not _necessarily_ wrong, one should be very mindful when overloading it for decorative purposes not to create accessibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

Border is included in box model, thus it will effect its adjacent elements(although box-sizing should work).

Instead we can use outline property of css which is not part of box model apparently, so it won't affect its adjacent elements. I found this solution from [outline | CSS-TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/#:%7E:text=The%20outline%20property%20in%20CSS,elements%20(nice%20for%20debugging!))

```css
.hover-border {
  display: block;
}

.hover-border:hover {
  outline: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
}
```