# Why am I getting an empty space between the border-bottom of a list item and a div beneath it?

Tags: html, css

Why is it that, when hovering over the Academics list item, we get an extra empty space between the border-bottom of academics and the div beneath it of class "slideshow-container"?

Example of it working properly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIoQL.png)

Example of it not working properly (only case):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdRyV.jpg)

html code:

```
<nav class="mainNav">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="RHU LOGO">
        <ul class="navItems">
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownList">Academics
                <div class="dropdownContent">
                    <a href="GPA.html">GPA</a>
                    <a href="GPA.html">Study Plan</a>
                    <a href="GPA.html">Course Registration</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">X-Files</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>
    <br />
```

CSS Code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@700&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#bodyHomepage {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

footer {
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mainNav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-bottom: lightgray solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainNav img {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}

.navItems {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: fit-content;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.navItems li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}


.navItems li a, .navItems li {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #734b6d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navItems li>a:hover{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: #734b6d 5px solid;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .mainNav {
        justify-content: center;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }

    .navItems li a:hover {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom: #734b6d 5px solid;
    }
}

.dropdownList:hover{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom:#734b6d 5px solid;
} 

.dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    /* position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1; */
}

/* .dropdownContent a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdownContent a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
} */

/* .dropdownList:hover .dropdownContent {display: block;} */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the padding-bottom that you're adding:

```
.dropdownList:hover{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom:#734b6d 5px solid;
}
```

And then the width of the border. Try something like the following from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18887137/9587457):

```
.dropdownList {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.dropdownList:hover{
/*    padding-bottom: 20px; */
    border-bottom:#734b6d 5px solid;
}
```

Here you can see a stripped down version in action, using the OP code from above:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@700&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#bodyHomepage {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

footer {
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mainNav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-bottom: lightgray solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainNav img {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}

.navItems {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: fit-content;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.navItems li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}


.navItems li a, .navItems li {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #734b6d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navItems li>a:hover{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: #734b6d 5px solid;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .mainNav {
        justify-content: center;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }

    .navItems li a:hover {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom: #734b6d 5px solid;
    }
}

.dropdownList {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.dropdownList:hover{
/*    padding-bottom: 20px; */
    border-bottom:#734b6d 5px solid;
} 

.dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    /* position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1; */
}

/* .dropdownContent a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdownContent a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
} */

/* .dropdownList:hover .dropdownContent {display: block;} */
htmlcss
```

```html
<nav class="mainNav">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="RHU LOGO">
        <ul class="navItems">
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownList">Academics
                <div class="dropdownContent" style="display:inline">
                    <a href="GPA.html">GPA</a>
                    <a href="GPA.html">Study Plan</a>
                    <a href="GPA.html">Course Registration</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">X-Files</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    >
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img
                src="images/slideshow3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>
    <br />
```